# Angular-4 :Using checkboxes for multi select

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular4-forms

Using Angular 4--How can I remove an item from an array when a checkbox is unchecked?
Can someone please show the component function that does so would look like???
Thanks a lot.
My codes are as follows :

```
**app.component.html:**

<div>
<h2>SAMPLE</h2>
<input [(ngModel)] = "newItem" type="text" placeholder="Add Item">
<button (click)="addItem()">ADD</button>
<ul *ngFor="let i of Items ; let ind=index" >
<li><input type="checkbox" [checked]="stat" (click)="flagged(ind)" >{{i}}</li>
</ul>
<ul *ngFor="let f of flaggedItems"><li>
<h3>Flagged array : {{f}}</h3>
</li></ul>
</div>


**app.component.ts :**

flagged(index) {
    this.toggler();
    this.i = 0;
    while (this.i < this.flaggedItems.length )
        {
        if ( index === this.flaggedItems[this.i]){
          this.presentin = this.i;
          this.present = true;
          break;
        }
      this.i++;
       }
       if (this.stat === true && !this.present) {
          this.flaggedItems.push(index);
       }
    else {
         this.flaggedItems.splice( this.presentin, 1);
       }
  }

  toggler() {
    if (!this.stat){
      //this.pr = 'checked';
      this.stat = true;
     }
    else {
      //this.pr = 'Unchecked';
      this.stat = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: so what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with.

```
(change)="doSomething($event)"
```

This is probably the most appropriate event for dealing with checkboxes.